# AWS Credentials in Code: How to do it securely?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm building analytics features for game companies and I want to add AWS Integration. Analytics run in the background and should send the saved data from the player's PC to an S3 bucket. So I've created an IAM user who's only permission is to put objects in the bucket. I then generated an access key and secret key for the IAM user.

What I can't figure out is how to securely store the credentials in code. My biggest hope was the SecretsManager, but to access the SecretsManager you need to provide credentials again, and then you can just get the secret credentials in a neat json.

I feel like I'm going about this all the wrong ways but the AWS documentation is so vast that I don't know where to look.

This works, but post this code on GitHub and anyone can put anything they want in your S3 bucket:

```cs
// These are example keys they don't do much
public const string accessKey = "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE";
public const string secretKey = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";

public AWSCredentials credentials => new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
```

This doesn't work yet (`AmazonServiceException`), but even if it did then what's stopping anyone from reading my keys?

```cs
[Serializable]
private struct CredentialKeys
{
    public string accessKey;
    public string secretKey;
}

public async Task<AWSCredentials> GetCredentials()
{
    var response = // code for getting secret (not sure if Amazon allows me showing it here).
    
    var json = response.SecretString;
    var keys = JsonUtility.FromJson<CredentialKeys>(json);
    return new BasicAWSCredentials(keys.accessKey, keys.secretKey);
}
```

Comment: Another approach is to use a server cluster or lambda that the clients connect to via HTTPS.  Then you can use the security/firewall/DDoS protections AWS offers, and the clients do not have any IAM credentials at all.  Servers might be cheaper than lambdas for high traffic.  Also, AWS offers Kinesis for activity tracking and Dynamo for fast DB storage, one of those might make more sense than S3.

Comment: You don't store them in code. Provide them as env vars. If you have to run something on machines you don't control, have them authenticate with a server where you _can_ securely store the credentials.

Comment: ^ but still assume that the credentials will be harvested with a hacked client or man-in-the-middle attack.  The advantage of a server or lambda acting as a proxy between clients and S3 is it's harder to poison the S3 storage -- since the clients never get actual IAM credentials they can't for example write 1 million 4 GB files.